# Using angular-tour with multiple views produces unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use the angular-tour plugin to give a short tour of a sites functionality. I would like the tool tips to pop on each icon found in the horizontal navbar. The navbar is a view and even though I have included the required scripts etc in the index.html, it is just rendering text, and that is also being cut off by the main view. This makes sense but how can I fix this?

I have also included angular-tour in angular.module. I appreciate any help.I have also included a screenshot of what it looks like currently (the plain text "Highlighted"). I am just trying to implement the example from http://daftmonk.github.io/angular-tour/ to my application before editing.[image]

**index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Scrummage</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/normalize.css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css">
  <link href="../bower_components/angular-tour/dist/angular-tour.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-drag-and-drop-lists/angular-drag-and-drop-lists.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-modal/angular-ui-modal.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-charts/dist/angular-charts.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/d3/d3.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/services/utils.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/controllers/signin/signin.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/controllers/storyBoard/storyBoard.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/controllers/analytics/analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="./js/controllers/featureSetup/featureSetup.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-tour/dist/angular-tour-tpls.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="scrummage">

  <div ui-view

  ></div>

</body>

</html>
```

**navbar.html:**

```
<div class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="grow fa fa-gear nav-list-icon"></i></a>
<tour step="currentStep">
  <span tourtip="tip 1"> Highlighted </span>
  <span tourtip="tip 2"> Elements </span>
  <input tourtip="You can use it as an attribute on your element" />
  <span tourtip="Full options"
        tourtip-step="3"
        tourtip-next-label="Next"
        tourtip-placement="right"
        tourtip-offset="60">Full options</span>
</tour>
      </li>
      <div id= "analyticsModal" ng-controller='analyticsCtrl'>
      <li><a href = "#" ng-click="open()"><i class="grow fa fa-area-chart nav-list-icon"></i></a></li> 
            <div modal="showModal"  close="cancel()" ng-include="'../js/controllers/analytics/analytics.html'"></div>
      </div>
      <div id= "featureSetupModal" ng-controller='featureSetupCtrl'>
      <li><a href="#" ng-click="open()"><i class="grow fa fa-plus"></i></a></li>
          <div class="featureModal" modal="showModal" close="cancel()" ng-include="'../js/controllers/featureSetup/featureSetup.html'"></div>
      </div>
      <li><a href="/logout"><i class="grow fa fa-sign-out"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong. Basically, the view that the screenshot above shows is from a view that was included in another view, and I missed having the:

```
$scope.currentStep = -1;
```

in the parent view scope.